# UFT API TEST: Create SQL query based on values from previous step activity at run time

Tags: web-services, rest, hp-uft

Steps to be performed in UFT API Test:

1. Get JSON RESPONSE from added REST activity in test flow
2. Add Open DB connection activity
3. Add Select Data activity with query string

   `SELECT Count(*) From Table1 Where COL1 = 'XXXX' and COL2 = '   1234'`

(here COL2 value has length of 7 characters including spaces)

In the above query values in where clause is received(dynamically at run time) from JSON response.

When i try to link the query value using link to data source with custom expression
eg:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 Where COL1 = 
'{Step.ResponseBody.RESTACTIVITYxx.OBJECT[1].COL1}' and COL2 = 
'{Step.ResponseBody.RESTACTIVITYxx.OBJECT[1].COL2}'
```

then the QUERY changed (excluding spaces in COL2) to:

`SELECT Count(*) From Table1 Where COL1 = 'XXXX' and COL2 = '1234'`

I eventried with concatenate and Replace string activity but same happens.

Please kindly help..

Comment: Yes it is dynamic, it is fetched from db ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StringConcatenation action, to build de Query String.
Use the String as Query in Database "Select data"